# Combining two .T.plots into one graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

So looking around i've seen a few posts about combining graphs online,but none seem to apply to the graphs im using. while i'm happy to use matplotlib I can't seem to get my code to work in that while it does work in panda.

```
df = pd.read_excel (r'FILE-Location', index_col='PT: TD: BP')
df.iloc[1:2].T.plot()
df.iloc[2:3].T.plot()
```

These are the two seperate plots I wish to plot onto the same graph. I know it's a weird request and I could very easily combine them by making it [1:3] however I wish to keep them seperate as I plan to have them as options on tkinter, in which you can check a box of which lines you would like displayed, in order to do this I have to keep them seperate.

Thanks for any help solving this.

Edit: thanks for linking a similiar post, I tested the methods given there and they all seemed to simply plot into four seperate graphs within the same figure, while im looking for all four overlayed onto the same graph.

Comment: FYI, pandas uses matplotlib under the hood.

Comment: Maybe `ax=df.iloc[1:2].T.plot()` and `df.iloc[1:2].T.plot(ax=ax)`? Maybe you could add more precise information about how df looks like?

Comment: @JohanC perfect thanks! Works exactly like I needed.